# Ionic angular Preload all module only on device

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native

How to use preload all strategy on device and nopreload on browser?
we can load all module like this:

```
imports: [
CommonModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules }),
...
],
```

This will preload all module in any platform,
But i want to prevent preload when running on browser. And it must  only preload on device

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve and what have you tried so far?

Comment: My app size is large and Latency is not my problem in web.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible with Ionic's `Platform` and Angular `PreloadingStrategy`. You need to have a custom preloading strategy. Here is a sample strategy doing what you want.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadingStrategy, Route } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LocalOnlyPreloadingStrategy implements PreloadingStrategy {
    constructor(private platform: Platform) { }
    public preload(route: Route, fn: () => Observable<boolean>): Observable<boolean> {
        if (this.platform.is('hybrid')) {
            // Running on a device
            return fn();
        }
        // Not running on a device
        return of(false);
    }
}
```

You can import and use just like you are using `PreloadAllModules` in your code.

```
imports: [
CommonModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { preloadingStrategy: LocalOnlyPreloadingStrategy }),
...
],
providers: [LocalOnlyPreloadingStrategy]
```

For more information;

- https://celilsemi.erkiner.com/blog/ionic-angular-preload-modules-only-on-device/
- https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/platform
- https://angular.io/api/router/PreloadingStrategy